# Regex agrupacion bloque dinamico alfanumerico

Tags: regex

Necesito ayuda porque he intentado de varias formas crear una expresión regular que me salga por grupos pero he tenido problemas con una variación que no se como tener en cuenta:

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4yFpkL/1)

**Entrada:**

```
589011 T CANNELLE FLAVOR 8
538160 TP0597C ORANGE FLAVOR
557137 APL0397C STRAWBERRY FLAVOR
556137 APL0397C STRAWBERRY FLAVOR
545129 1APL0397C MANGO FLAVOR
984320 TRANS DECENAL
533160 TP0597C ORANGE FLAVOR
530373 A PINEAPPLE FLAVOR
059311 A STRAWBERRY FLAVOR
508142 T LEMON FLAVOR
547261 A BLACKBERRY FLAVOR
536564 2T BLUEBERRY STRAWBERRY
055406 A MILK FLAVOR
054945 A BLACKBERRY FLAVOR
983347 SUSTANE
902040 ACETIC ACID
```

Salida:
**Grupo 1:**

```
589011 T
538160 TP0597C
557137 APL0397C
556137 APL0397C
545129 1APL0397C
984320
533160 TP0597C
530373 A
059311 A
508142 T
547261 A
536564 2T
055406 A
054945 A
983347
902040
```

**Grupo 2:**

```
CANNELLE FLAVOR
ORANGE FLAVOR
STRAWBERRY FLAVOR
STRAWBERRY FLAVOR
MANGO FLAVOR
TRANS DECENAL
ORANGE FLAVOR
PINEAPPLE FLAVOR
STRAWBERRY FLAVOR
LEMON FLAVOR
BLACKBERRY FLAVOR
BLUEBERRY STRAWBERRY
MILK FLAVOR
BLACKBERRY FLAVOR
SUSTANE
ACETIC ACID
```

Regex Test:

1. `(\d+\s?[A-Z0-9]*)\s+([A-Z\s]+)\s`
2. `^([0-9\s]+(?:[A-Z0-9]+)?)\s(?:[A-Z\s]+)`

La dificultad que se me presenta son estas dos entradas:

```
988320 TRANS DECENAL
903040 ACETIC ACID
```

debido a que los grupos deben ser de esta manera:

**Grupo 1:**

```
988320
903040
```

**Group 2:**

```
TRANS DECENAL
ACETIC ACID
```

y no así que es como queda actualmente:

**Grupo 1:**

```
988320 TRANS
903040 ACETIC
```

**Group 2:**

```
DECENAL
ACID
```

Comment: Creo que deberías explicar mejor la entrada y que esperas que haya en cada grupo.

Comment: No entiendo. En qué se diferencian esos 2 casos del resto y por qué deberías tratarlos de otra manera? Y en qué lenguaje estás programado?

Comment: No esta claro que salida esperas. Los ultimos dos ejemplos pueden existir? los dos tipos de regex pueden aparecer?